# Android: Save state of list view using savedInstanceState

Tags: java, android

I have a standard implementation of a `ListView` (one which uses an Array Adapter) and one of the in-built layouts `R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`.

Anyway, I was reading about `Activity` lifecycle and how when the screen orientation changes or if a phone call occurs, one way to restore the `Activity` state is using the `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods.

My question is, can someone help me how can I store the state of a `ListView` (not customised) into a bundle, this includes its entries, position and checked items

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want your data to be persistent. For that you have to use SQLite database or SharedPreferences. You can also use device's internal storage or external storage according to your needs. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) is the link which will provide detailed explanation.

`onSaveInstanceState` is for instances when accidentally your App's data is lost like by killing the process or when a phone call comes. You cannot store data in `onSaveInstanceState` deliberately to retrieve it according to your needs.